# Address Validation using Fedex API in C# - Getting Authentication Failed error

Tags: c#, fedex

I want to integrate Address validation using Fedex API to my application. I got the c# code that uses AddressValidationService of Fedex Web Services for it. But when I process it using our FedEx Web Services API User Key, FedEx Web Services API Password, FedEx AccountNumber, FedEx MeterNumber in test environment we got an Error with Error Meassage as "Authentication Failed", Code as "1000" and Source as "prof". I also tried by changing the value of "requirePermission" as true in config file(as below)

```
     <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System,
     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
     <section name="AddressValidationWebServiceClient.Properties.Settings"          type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,          PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="true" />
```

But still the Error remains. Do I need any more data to get this service?

**UPDATE:**
My issue has been solved. The reason for the issue was that my FedEx account didn't had permission for address validation processing, and it has been solved when I contacted FedEx support and they gave permission for processing address validation request to my account.